# Why Promise is executed before setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, es6-promise

Here I have written 3 `console.log()`. Please help me, why `Promise` is executed before `setTimeout` even if it has 0 second delay. As per my understanding both `setTimeout` and `Promise` are executed in webAPI not in JavaScript Engine. Is this thing is related to priorty?

```
setTimeout(()=>console.log("SET TIME OUT"),0);  // #1

var promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    resolve()
})
promise
    .then(()=>console.log("PROMISE"))          // #2
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))

console.log("SIMPLE CONSOLE LOG");             // #3
```

OutPut :

```
SIMPLE CONSOLE LOG
PROMISE
SET TIME OUT
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Promise` execution happens as part of the *microtask* queue processing phase.

When you have a `setTimeout` function callback scheduled, that function is added to the event loop's  *macrotask* queue and executed when the last running code in the main execution context stack is finished. Then on the next tick of the event loop the task/function is de-queued from the event loop *macrotask* queue and executed by the JavaScript engine.

But in case of `Promise`, if there is `Promise` task queued, that will be set in a *microtask* queue. Which is executed after all the code in the main execution context stack is done and before the next tick of the event loop happens. The next task from the *macrotask* queue is only picked up when the tasks in the *microtask* queue is completely exhausted.

It doesn't matter if you have the `setTimeout` callback scheduled at `0` milisecond. The priority is such that before the tasks in the *macrotask* queue is de-queued for processing in the next tick of the event loop, the *microtask* queue will be processed before that.

Some examples of asynchronous tasks which are queued in the macrotask queue:

`setTimeout`, `setInterval`, `setImmediate`, I/O tasks

Examples of asynchronous tasks in microtask queue:

`process.nextTick` (node), `Promise` API

Comment: Many thanks for the help, I will go checkout `microtask` and `macrotask`.